# PHP form processing and validation is not working

Tags: php, forms, validation, processing

I have the following code for my form, and it doesn't seem to work, the query does not insert after all the fields have been filled. I'll really appreciate it if someone can look at it and help me correct any mistake. The method for the form is post and the action is `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`. This is my first code in PHP so kind of new here Thanks.

```
<?php
  $counter=1;
  if (isset($_POST["post"])) {
    $gender= $_POST['gender'];
    $fname= $_POST['fname'];
    $lname= $_POST['lname'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $fone= $_POST['fone'];
    $school= $_POST['skuul'];
    $other= $_POST['other'];
    $output_form=false;
    $is_error = false;

    if (empty($email)) {
      echo "Please enter your email or contact info. \n";
      $output_form = $is_error = true;
    }

    if (empty($lname)) {
      echo "Please enter your email or contact info. \n";
      $output_form= $is_error = true;
    }

    if (empty($fone)) {
      echo "Please enter your email or contact info. \n";
      $output_form= $is_error = true;
    }

    if (empty($fname)) {
      echo "Please enter your name. \n";
      $output_form= $is_error = true;
    }

    if ($output_form) { 
      $query= "INSERT INTO 'elect_conference' ('gender', 'fname', 'lname', 'phone',                                 'email', 'School', 'course', 'other')".
      "values ('$gender', '$fname', '$lname', '$fone', '$email', '$school', '$course', '$other');";
      $result = execute($query);
      echo '<article class="extra-wrap">'."Hello $name congratulations, you are the                                  number $counter member registered for the ELECT Conference.
      A confirmation will be sent to your email ($email) within five(5) hours.\n
      Thank you. And have a nice day.</artice>";
      $fname="";
      $lname="";
      $fone="";
      $email="";
      $fone="";
      $school="";
      $subject="";
      $counter++;
    } else {
      echo "Please ensure that all the fields are approprietly filled";}
    } else {
      $output_form=true;
    }
    if ($output_form) {
  ?>
  <body id="page2">
    <!--==============================header=================================-->
    <section id="content">
      <div class="pad">
        <div class="main">
          <article class="grid_9 suffix_1">
            <div class="form1">
              <div class="padding">
                <h4 class="border-bot2 img-indent-bot" align="center" style="color:#00C !important">
                  ELECT Conference <br/>Registration
                </h4>
                <form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"               method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <fieldset>
                    <div style="margin-left:90px !important;"><?php echo "$counter/500"; ?></div>
                    <div class="rowElem0">
                      <span class="radio">Personal Infomation:</span>
                      <span class="radio2">
                      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr" checked>
                      <label class="ratio">Mr</label>
                      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs">
                      <label class="ratio">Ms</label>
                      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs">
                      <label class="ratio">Mrs</label>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rowElem">
                    <label><span class="input">First Name:</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rowElem">
                    <label><span class="input">Last Name:</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rowElem">
                    <label><span class="input">Phone:</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="fone" value="<?php echo $fone; ?>"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rowElem">
                      <label><span class="input">E-mail:</span></label>
                      <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rowElem1">
                    <input type="radio" name="graduate" id="chbox4" checked>
                    <strong><label class="check2">Graduate?</label></strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rowElem">
                    <label><span class="input">School:</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="skuul" value="<?php echo $school; ?>"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rowElem">
                    <label><span class="input">Course:</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="course" value="<?php echo $school; ?>"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rowElem1">
                    <input type="radio" name="other" id="chbox5">
                    <strong><label class="check2">Other</label></strong>
                    <label><span class="input">Specify:</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="other" value="<?php echo $other; ?>"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="buttons">
                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
</body>
<?php
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Your "    $query= "INSERT INTO 'elect_conference' ..." code is seriously messed up...

Comment: There are some obvious errors that may be typos in writing the question; for example, your `$query` string definition has some values that repeat after the semicolon (`,$other');";'email', 'School'` etc.); your tag `<article>` is "closed" with a `</artice>` tag, you have `enter code here` in various places... Please fix what you can - and tell us what is not working for you in detail (not just "it's not working").

Comment: one of your `<article` tags is misspelled too. You need to learn to indent your code properly to help yourself make it more readable too.

Comment: Your `<form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">` is also seriously messed up.

Answer (score -1):

Please show the form code, and be specific in the outcome of the form processing. What exactly didn't work?

In the mean time here are a couple of observations:

1. Instead of assigning each `$_POST` element at a time you can do this:

   `foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value)  $$key = $value;`
2. `*$output_form*` and `*$is_error*` always have the same value, why the duplication?

Comment: doing `foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) $$key = $value;` can be dangerous.  If this were added into the current code I could make a custom post to the page and pass counter as `<script>alert("You've been hijacked");</script>` and that would javascript would run on the page. It's called cross site scripting and it's a no-no